# Реактивная работа с сетью (VK, VKDSK)

Tags: android, вконтакте, rxjava, android-vksdk

Использую VKSDK для скачивания информации по пользователю (`VKApi.friends()`), необходимо сделать несколько запросов (например 50). Как правильно решить данную проблему? Для каждого запроса создавать новый поток? Скорее всего, правильно будет дожидаться ответа от предыдущего запроса и потом делать новый? Для этого, как я понял, подходит RxJava2 (чтобы самому не громоздить велосипеды). После нескольких дней изучения RxJava2 сейчас такая каша в голове. Кроме того, судя по всему, `Observable`/`Observer` нельзя обернуть вокруг VKSDK. Так ли это? Если можно -
 подскажите в двух словах как это сделать или дайте ссылку на инфу, где можно почитать на эту тему (rus/eng). Слишком уж много различных подходов для реализации этого..

Вот код попытки обернуть RxJava вокруг VKSDK:

```
Observable.just(request = VKApi.friends().get(parameters)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .flatMap(s -> {

                    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                            Log.d("ListFriends", "onComplete");

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(VKError error) {

                            Log.d("ListFriends", "onError");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {

                            Log.d("ListFriends", "Failed");
                        }
                    });

                    return ???

                }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
```

Comment: Можно средствами SDK отправить [несколько запросов одним запросом](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk?f=4.3.%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2). Обернуть в Rx вообще не проблема)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб по поводу средств SDK я видел этот класс, но у 
`VKBatchRequest` нет сеттера, а кол-во запросов каждый раз разное, соответственно нужно делать в цикле, а перед новым запросом нужно дожидаться ответа, конечно я мог бы сделать свой велосипед (создать отдельный поток, который бы следил за флагом, флаг менялся при получении данных и отправке запроса, что, собственно, я уже писал в прошлом вопросе). Исправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь. 
По поводу Rx вроде начал разбираться, добавил код в вопрос. В правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь?

Comment: Не совсем верно. Если кратко, то как-то так создаёте `Observable` - `Observable.fromCallable(()->request.execute()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`. Создаёте их в цикле, потом объединяете в один как-то так: `Observable.zip(observablesList, arrOfResultsOnObjectArr -> ТУТ_КОД_ПРЕОБРАЗОВАНИЯ_МАССИВА_OBJECT_В_МАССИВ_ЮЗЕРОВ)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ох благодарю, буду разбираться!

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте, всё же, изучил `VKBatchRequest` - там можно в конструктор передать массив запросов. В предложенном выше коде вы скорее всего сразу же упрётесь в лимит кол-ва запросов в секунду. Т.е. работать не будет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а разве средствами RxJava нельзя дожидаться ответа от предыдущего запроса, а потом вызывать следующий?? А лимит да, там он присутствует и в последующих запросах возвращается fail

Comment: Можно. Но представьте, что у вас лимит - 5 запросов в секунду на все девайсы, где стоит приложение и вам надо за раз 100К запросов послать.Это 5 часов на одном девайсе. Думаю, с VKBatchRequest должно быстрее получиться - его, вроде, как раз для этого и придумали.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и правда! Там в конструкторе есть  `VKRequest[]`, как же я его сразу не заметил. Благодарю! Как допишу то, что задумал, всё равно пойду изучать rx)
Ваш предыдущий комментарий как раз таки и является ответом на мой вопрос, можете оформить как ответ, если хотите :)

Comment: Да, rx изучить точно стоит)